# Show only month in the caption

Tags: react-day-picker

I am using [react-day-picker](https://github.com/gpbl/react-day-picker) to power up my website.

I use multi-select mode depicting two months side by side,and i want to show only months in the caption omitting the year. Is there any option in the day-picker that would enable me to do this?

[image: caption]

Answer (score 0):

[image]Yes you have to pass `canChangeYear` and `canChangeMonth` props as `false` to `DayPicker` component.

```
<DayPicker  canChangeYear={false} canChangeMonth={false} numberOfMonths={2}/>
```

Comment: hey Zhora Khachatryan have you tried my answer? was it helpful ?